# How to check if my Android App is Disconnected from Google Fit App

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I've disconnected manually my app from Google Fit App -> Manage connected apps -> my app -> Disconnected as stated at [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6098255?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).
Now I want to know is there any way to know connection status on my app when I start it?

Comment: Your app is good once it's disconnected. Unfortunately there's no way to know the connection status